Unity how to call a function after a scene is loaded but before Awake or OnEnable are called?
When my scene is loaded, I want to load some data from my save system. This needs to happen ideally before each object’s Awake and OnEnable functions are called. What is the best way to do this?
Naive attempt:
if (levelLoadParamaters.saveGameDataBeforeLoad)
{
    saveSystemManager.Save();
}

SceneManager.LoadScene(scene.BuildIndex);

if (levelLoadParamaters.loadGameDataAfterLoad)
{
    saveSystemManager.Load();
}

This does not work as saveSystemManager.Load(); is called when we are still in the old scene, before the new scene objects are loaded.
The documentation explains this.

When using SceneManager.LoadScene, the scene loads in the next frame

My next attempt was to use SceneManager.sceneLoaded

private void OnEnable()
{
    SceneManager.sceneLoaded += SceneLoaded;
}

private void SceneLoaded(Scene newScene, LoadSceneMode loadMode)
{
    Debug.Log($"{nameof(SceneManager.sceneLoaded)} invoked to \"{newScene.name}\"");
    saveSystemManager.Load();
}


However, this seems to happen after object's Awake and OnEnable
Log:

Player Awake


sceneLoaded invoked to "scene"

The documentation for this is terrible, but it seems this is intended behaviour.
My only other idea would be to create an object in each scene with this load function in its Awake and push it to the front of the execution order. But this seems a pretty hacky solution.
Is there a better way to invoke some logic as soon as a scene loads, before Awake and OnEnable?
EDIT:
Attempting to do this using async scene loading will also not work as even after the scene has reached "90% progress (fully loaded)" and is waiting for allowSceneActivation, it is not actually loaded in, and cannot be interacted with . Allowing it to then load is equivalent to the naive attempt above.

sceneLoaded's docs state:

You can expect to receive the sceneLoaded notification after OnEnable but before Start for all objects in the scene

So that's not what you want. There is allowSceneActivation, along with SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync, where you can manually enable a scene instead of the SceneManager doing it for you. This should delay Awake/OnEnable/Start calls until you manually activate the scene by setting allowSceneActivation back to true:
public IEnumerator LoadSceneWithSaveData(string scene) {
    AsyncOperation op = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(scene);
    op.allowSceneActivation = false;

    // 0.9 (90%) is used as a magic number, scene activation makes up the last 10%
    while (!op.isDone && op.progress < 0.9f) {
        yield return null;
    }

    // At this point, `scene` is loaded but *not* active.
    // Do your save logic here.
    
    // And finally... enable the scene.
    op.allowSceneActivation = true;
}

Just be sure to start your scene load as a coroutine...
StartCoroutine(LoadSceneWithSaveData("scene name"));

The only problem after this is... well... the scene isn't active yet. Which might cause issues getting references to GameObjects / calling events, since the new objects wouldn't have the chance to subscribe to them. Are you sure your save system needs to run before even Awake?

Unfortunately, this does not solve my problem. I need to load my data after the previous scene is unloaded and after the incoming scene is active, just before awake/enable, this doesn't really do either of those. this is equivalent to my naive approach in fact.

Then it's most likely not possible, since Awake is called while the scene is activating. Best way would probably be to you refactor your code to not use Awake, maybe using an event as an additional "on save data loaded" callback instead.

I don't think "Don't use Awake" is a serious suggestion, but thanks for taking the time to answer.

The only other way you can realistically run your own code before any object has Awake called is by having every object except your save manager script start disabled (probably via a disabled global parent object); then enabling them when the save is done loading. (Since Awake doesn't run for disabled objects.)   But that's a dirty hack, which is why I suggested moving away from using Awake and using your own callback initiated by the save system.

Yeah both those would work, I'd probably just have a specialised object whose awake runs first. I was just looking to see if a more Unity Intended way to do this existed. Both those ideas would require a whole lot of work.

@Jay, "Don't use Awake" is a serious suggestion. If your save system needs to run before Awake, then there is most likely an issue with the way it works. ipodtouch0218's suggestion of using callbacks/delegates is a great way to handle object initialization.

@Jay I'd agree with the above - don't use Awake then. I can recommend to use a dependency injection driven approach (you don't need to use an actual DI library for this). Have a central manager initialize the application/scene - this way you have full control over what happens when and can delay later initialization until your loading is done. Alternatively: Make use of Start and put in Awake only the things that can happen before the loading and delay everything else into Start so your loading has time to happen before

Not quite what is being looked for here as this will only work on the very first loaded scene of the game, but for completeness, this is possible.
A solution is possible using this attribute:
[RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod]

With the following parameter:
RuntimeInitializeLoadType.BeforeSceneLoad

Like so:
[RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod(RuntimeInitializeLoadType.BeforeSceneLoad)]
static void OnBeforeSceneLoad()
{
    Debug.Log("First scene loading: Before Awake is called.");
}

This function will be bound to a callback invocation happening after objects are loaded in but before Awake (or OnEnable) are called.
From the docs


The first scene starts loading.
Then BeforeSceneLoad callback is invoked. Here objects of the scene are loaded but Awake() has not been called yet. All objects are.
considered inactive here.
Awake() and OnEnable() are invoked on MonoBehaviours.


The full list of subscribable scene loading events are as follows (in order)

SubsystemRegistration
AfterAssembliesLoaded
BeforeSplashScreen
BeforeSceneLoad
AfterSceneLoad

Note again, these are only invoked for the first scene loaded in the entire project. These will only be invoked once in the lifetime of your program.

A solution that can help is opening the profiler and determining what the first Awake() method runs. You can then run your load info in the first Awake() call. It isn't perfect but it can help load a lot of the info in the beginning.
This link shows you how to use the profiler: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html
This other link leads to the script execution order (Given by Jay in comments):
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html ;)

That also works. I had the profiler in mind but that option also works. Why wouldn't using that solution to determine when you can run your load info on the first awake. Because like ipodtouch mentions in the comments for their answer, there aren't many other options besides just starting to run code in the start and having the load info run on awake.

Yeah i discuss this in my question. It's probably the solution i'll go with. I was just asking if there was a more officail way of doing this becuase it seems really hacky :p

In no way is it hacky. It is quite common to need to work with the execution order and profiler when trying to optimize your code or find where a bottleneck for your project is.

Maybe I don't want to see what you would consider a hack then aha...

Some code on Unity's official documentation for VR had some code that would get the controllers and set them to a variable in the update method while the variable had a datatype var.  I forgot how I found the code on the website because it took me a while and it wasn't on the base page for VR instruction. I want to say it had to do with controller vibration but I don't remember it's been a couple of years now. The other programmers and I were just astonished by it.

Hope the answer helped with your concern/question.

@MontainProduction hehe just because Unity official components do certain things doesn't mean it is less hacky ;) in contrary some of them are extremely hacky and that's the reason why this kind of questions has to be asked ;)

My solution to this is creating a MonoBehaviour script and making sure it's the first in the Script Execution Order in Project Settings. It's Awake is guaranteed to be called first in the whole scene. You can use this as an attach point for any code you want to run before any other Awake.
It also works with Start, Update and FixedUpdate, if you don't want to use PlayerLoop. It won't work with OnDestroy and OnDisable though, and the only way to do something after all object perform OnDestroy is in the first Awake of the next scene AFAIK.
In my case I use two such scripts PreSceneScript, placed first in the execution order, and PostSceneScript, placed last. I first initialize global stuff in the first Awake, then allow all objects to initialize with their Awake, and lastly I load saved data in the last Awake. All the save dependent initialization is done in Start, so each object has the ability to do stuff before and after save data is loaded.

Yeah I discuss this solution in the question, I was asking if there was a way to achieve this behaviour without requiring a specific monobehaviour to exist in each scene. Something like RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod but triggerable more than once. Looks like there isn't.

Sorry, I must've paid too little attention when reading your question. To my knowledge, there's no other way. And I did look, more in the context of calling some code after the last OnDestroy, but that one's even harder ;)
